# iPhone E-Mail Cache

Tags: iphone

This is a general iPhone usability question. I wanted to know if we can clear contact cache in email of iPhone mail account?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible right now, but many people have filed a radar report to request an option to reset this cache in the Settings app (in the same view where it's possible to reset your network settings, etc..).

The only way would be to clear the entire contents of your iPhone and **don't** restore from any backup.

Comment: Yup, restore as new http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4137 is the only option to permanently clear the sms or email cache at the moment.

Comment: @hobs - "Restore as new"? As far as I know, restoring is from a backup.

Comment: Hey @NicolasBarbulesco, fair point, I could have said it as "Restore the software on the device to its original state", or better as "wiping it entirely"