# How to clear iPhone's concact cache for text messages?

Tags: contacts, iphone

My iPhone (model 5, IOS 6.1.2) seems to have some sort of contact cache which it uses when sending text messages: whenever I am sending a message to someone, I start typing the persone's name in te "to:" field, and the iPhone shows me all the contacts matching the letters I typed; *but it shows up also contacts I have deleted long ago, and which I don't want around anymore*.

How can I get rid of this?

Is this related to the infamous [e-mail cache](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7743/iphone-e-mail-cache)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been ***FINALLY*** fixed in IOS 7. Now you can remove contacts from this cache.

As soon as the unwanted contact pops up while you're typing in the "to:" field, you can tap on a little "i" (probably for "info") icon on its right, and have a menu appear where you can remove the contact, or add it back to your address book if you feel so inclined.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 9, go to Contacts and start typing the contact name of phone number. The cached contact will appear after any actual matching contacts. Touch the cached contact, then Edit, and then Delete Contact.

Answer (score 1):

I have an iPhone 6

1. Go to your Message screen (where you text from)
2. Click on the edit "icon" (upper right) Like you're going to start a new text
3. Enter a contact that has multiple people
4. Go to the multiple contact you want to get rid of and click on the little "i" with the circle around it
5. Click "Remove" A message will come up "Are you sure you want to remove this recent group?"
6. Click "Remove from recents" or "Cancel" to not remove it
7. Repeat for other multiple contacts you want to get rid of

Answer (score 0):

The one cached address that had multiple contacts did not show the little circle - I have used that before. So I deleted the conversation and lo and behold, that long list of contacts vanished!!

Answer (score -1):

Apparently you have to reset everything. It'll make the phone a "new phone", but I don't know exactly what will happen. I want to do it as well, because I have contacts that I want to just go away; but I'm nervous. I don't want to get rid of all of the contacts! Other than this, I don't know what there is. :/ I'm sorry.

Comment: Could you say why you have to reset everything e.g. where you learnt that from as a reasonable source should also give details of what happens

Answer (score -1):

This is an issue I have contended with for quite some time. I first noticed it with the iOS 6 rollout for iPhone 5. I have contacted Apple a number of times. The only way to clear the cache is a drastic, annoying total restore from new. I've posted to the Apple communities about the issue, but Apple deletes the postings saying that comments for future updates do not belong in the Apple Support Communities.