# iOS 9 iMessage notifications show sender's number, not name

Tags: messages, contacts, notifications, ios

After some annoying wifi problems with iOS 8.3, I tried out iOS 9 public beta 2 (now public beta 3) on my iPhone 5 (Edit: in the UK). When I receive a text message (iMessage/SMS), the lock screen/home screen notifications usually come up with the sender's phone number, not their name. This happens for most senders, even though their names and numbers are in my contacts.  When I open the Messages app, all messages are correctly categorised according to the contact's name, so my problem is only with the notifications. For some reason, notifications work correctly for one contact, but no others.

Questions:

- Is this a known bug?
- How can I work around it?

Comment: Possible workaround.. Pay close attention to the phone number format in the notifications, in the U.S. there is likely a prefix of "+1"... Making the number +1xxxyyyzzzz .  Try entering that format for the contact phone number.

Comment: If not USA please edit your country into the question. I could see this might be a country specific bug.

Comment: Yes, I've checked the country code format and it is identical to what's stored in contacts. Perhaps relevantly, the spacing is different, i.e. the stored number is +44 xxx xxx xxxx but the notifications show +44xxxxxxxxxx (no spaces).

Comment: Given this is likely a bug, be sure to [provide feedback to Apple](https://beta.apple.com/sp/en/betaprogram/faq) with included Feedback Assistant app!

Comment: Same problem here with the final release of iOS 9 on a 4s - also in the UK. Did you manage to find a workaround?

Comment: No, I didn't find a workaround. I reported the bug and went back to iOS 8.4.

Comment: However, after reinstalling 8.4 and then upgrading to 9.0 final, this problem seems to have disappeared. A very laborious fix in my case.

Comment: Also have this bug on iOS 9.0.1 in the UK

Answer (score 1):

On cause of numbers showing up instead of names is if there is a cached phone-number-only contact that needs to be [removed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/85184/19025).

Answer (score -1):

Have you restarted your device and not unlocked it since restarting? Due to the way encryption works on iOS contact data is encrypted until after the first time the device is unlocked after booting.

Google `NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication` for more information.

Comment: No, this still happens after unlocking.

Comment: Why the down votes? Just curious.